# Get HEX code of char using only native Windows 7 tools

Tags: windows-7, hexadecimal

I have a text file with a weird character that isn't printable. I want to know its HEX code.

How can I know it without installing software like [HexView](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/1HexView.shtml) or programming?

Comment: **You have eliminated all possible solutions by not allowing third-party software and programming.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell 2.0 is natively installed on any Windows 7 system, so it is possible.
Unfortunatly you have to do a little bit programming.

```
$strPath = "D:\test.txt"
Get-Content $strPath -Encoding Byte | ForEach-Object {        
        $ascii = [CHAR][BYTE]$_
        $hex = "{0:X2} " -f $_
        $dez = "{0:d} " -f $_
        write-host $ascii, $hex, $dez
    }
```

**Output** (in PowerShell ISE)

[image]

#### Source

- http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/get-hex-dumps-files-powershell
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/09/09/convert-hexadecimal-to-ascii-using-powershell.aspx (read it for a good laugh)

Answer (score 1):

For a single character, you can do this (in **powershell**):

```
'{0:X2}' -f [int]([byte][char]"A")

# <output>
# 41
```

For multi-byte (UTF-8/16/32) characters, you need to use something like this:

```
"0x{0:X}" -f [System.BitConverter]::ToUint32( [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF32.GetBytes( "" ) )

# <output>
# 0x1F44D
```